# How to get CPU or Memory usage of my chrome extension?

Tags: performance, google-chrome-extension

Is there a way I programmatically get CPU usage and memory usage for my chrome extension? I need to collect samples of CPU and memory usage and report it using an api.

Comment: I guess, [performance.memory](https://anonyco.github.io/wiki/apis/timing/properties/memory/) and [chrome.processes API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/processes)

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortunately, performance.memory is part of a project that is discontinued and chrome.processes is available only on users in dev channel. I want to take samples of CPU and memory usage for all my users. Any other alternative?

Comment: No alternatives, AFAIK. Also, the documentation may be obsolete so try it first.

Comment: @labyrinth I have the same need. 2 years later however, there is still no way as far as I know... performance.memory doesn't properly update.